# ExactTarget TriggeredSend Future Limit on Dataload

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-loader, bulk

I am trying to bulk insert Contacts that should be picked up by ExactTarget through the TriggeredSend but I am getting Future limits thrown.

Is there a different approach that would allow me to insert large amounts of Contact data and then get picked up by ExactTarget without any limit breach?

I should say that I am new to ExactTarget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the data loader, you can go into setting and change the Batch Size to less than 50 and it should help with that issue.